# How to use Concentration Inequalitites to bound this probability from above?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm attempting a problem in Rohatgi & Saleh's Intro to Probability and Statistics, from the Concentration inequalities section. It's actually the first exercise in the section, so the fact that I can't get it means I'm missing something obvious:

We have a random variable X with PDF: $f(x;\lambda) = \frac{e^{-x} x^\lambda}{\lambda !}, x>0$ for some $\lambda \geq 0$ an integer. They ask that I show that $P\{0<X<2(\lambda + 1)\} > \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + 1}$ .

I'd like to use the concentration/Markov/Chebyshev inequalities to for this but all the inequalities are in the wrong direction. Is there a nifty way I'm not thinking of to get them to mirror this result? Hints are greatly appreciated. Also please don't go easy on me if this is something obvious. I need to start being better at probability.

Also here are the concentration inequalities I've been referring to:

$$\text{If $E[h(X)]$ exists,  } \quad  P[h(X)\geq M] \leq \frac{E[h(X)]}{M} \quad \text{for any } M>0,\\
\text{If $E[|X|^k]$ exists,  } \quad  P[|X|\geq M] \leq \frac{E[|X|^k]}{M^k} \quad \text{for any } M>0,$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin by noticing that 
$$P(0 < X < 2(\lambda +1)) = P(-(\lambda +1) < X - (\lambda + 1) < \lambda +1) = P(|X - (\lambda + 1 )| < \lambda + 1)$$
Then, being good detectives and noticing that the numerator of our pdf correlates to $\Gamma(\lambda + 1) = \lambda!$, we have
$$ E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}x^{\lambda +1}}{\lambda!} = \frac{(\lambda +1)!}{\lambda!} = \lambda + 1$$
By a similar calculation, which I leave to you, we have that $E(X^2) = (\lambda +2)(\lambda + 1)$, and thus $$\sigma^2 = (\lambda + 1)[(\lambda +2) - (\lambda + 1)] = \lambda +1$$ 
So, letting $k = \sigma = \sqrt{\lambda +1}$, we have by Chebyshev's inequality
$$ P(|X - (\lambda + 1 )| < \lambda + 1) = 1 - P(|X - (\lambda + 1 )| \geq \lambda + 1) > \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + 1}$$ as required.